# Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку c++, предоставляющую многопоточную Loc-Free хеш-тблицу

Tags: c++, многопоточность, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, lock-free

Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку c++, предоставляющую многопоточную LocFree хеш-тблицу

Comment: в Qt есть хэш-таблица

Comment: @Lofectr - она не потокобезопасна

Comment: посмотрите в libcds: http://libcds.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я пользуюсь фейсбучной - https://github.com/facebook/folly
Лицензия Apache 2.0

Comment: А можно маленький примерчик? или ссылку на него